# Getting parameter in ADO.Net exception when calling from angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ado.net, asp.net-core-webapi

I had created an API in Dot net core. When I had tested it's working well & good through postman or ARC tools. But when calling from angular, It's throwing an sqlexception like : "An SqlParameter with parameter name @TotalRows is not contained by the SqlParameterCollection."
My wonder is how it's working in postman & why not in angular call.
My API dataaccess is like below :

```
public List<PoDetails> GetPoDetails(PoDetails pods, string vendor_id, out int TotalRows, int Timezone)
        {
            List<PoDetails> posList = new List<PoDetails>();
            TotalRows = 0;
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(conString);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_cc_get_po_details", con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd = Util.AddConditionalParameterString(cmd, "@vendor_id", vendor_id);
                cmd = Util.AddConditionalParameterString(cmd, "@sortBy", pods.sortBy);
                cmd = Util.AddConditionalParameterString(cmd, "@sortDirection", pods.sortDirection);
                cmd = Util.AddConditionalParameterInt(cmd, "@pageSize", pods.pageSize);
                cmd = Util.AddConditionalParameterInt(cmd, "@page", pods.page);
                cmd = Util.AddConditionalParameterInt(cmd, "@time_zone_offset", Timezone);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TotalRows", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmd.Parameters["@TotalRows"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                TotalRows = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@TotalRows"].Value);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    PoDetails posobj = new PoDetails();

                    posobj.vendor_name = dr["vendor_name"].ToString();
                    posobj.create_date = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["create_date"].ToString());
                    posobj.po_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["po_id"]);
                    posobj.po_amount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["po_amount"]);
                    posobj.invoice_count = Convert.ToInt32(dr["invoicecount"]);
                    if (dr["utilization_amount"] != DBNull.Value)
                        posobj.utilization_amount = Convert.ToInt32(dr["utilization_amount"]);
                    else
                        posobj.utilization_amount = 0;

                    posList.Add(posobj);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ec)
            {
                throw new Exception(ec.Message);
            }
            return posList;
        }
```

My procedure was like below :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_cc_get_po_details] 
( 
    @vendor_id              varchar(100) = null, 

    @sortBy             varchar(50)     = NULL,
    @sortDirection      varchar(50)     = null,
    @pageSize               int             = NULL,
    @page                   int             = NULL,
    @TotalRows              int             = NULL output,
    @time_zone_offset       int           = 0
  ) 
AS
BEGIN

  SELECT Count(I.invoice_id) as invoicecount, p.po_id,p.po_amount,p.vendor_id,
  DATEADD(MINUTE, @time_zone_offset, p.create_date) AS create_date , 
  v.vendor_name, sum(I.invoice_amount) as utilization_amount
    into #TempResults
    FROM  po_details p left join  invoice_details I on p.po_id = I.po_id
join vendor_details v on v.vendor_id = p.vendor_id
    WHERE (@vendor_id is null or @vendor_id = '' or v.vendor_id = @vendor_id)
    group by p.po_id, p.po_amount, p.vendor_id, p.create_date, v.vendor_name


    -- Paging Logic --
    Declare @StartingRow as int = 0
    Declare @FirstRow as int
    Declare @LastRow as int
    
    select  @TotalRows = count(*)
        from    #TempResults
    
    set @StartingRow = (@pageSize * @page) + 1

    if @pageSize is not null and @page is not null begin
        set @FirstRow = ((@page - 1) * @pageSize) + 1
        set @LastRow = @FirstRow + (@pageSize - 1)
    end else if @pageSize is not null and @StartingRow is not null begin
        set @FirstRow = @StartingRow
        set @LastRow = @FirstRow + (@pageSize - 1)
    end else begin
        set @FirstRow = 0
        set @LastRow = @TotalRows
    end
    ------
    -------------------
    
    --select @FirstRow;
    --select @LastRow;

    Select * from
    (
        Select ROW_NUMBER() over
        (
            order by
                case when @sortBy = 'vendor_id'   and   @sortDirection = 'desc' then vendor_id end desc,
                case when @sortBy = 'vendor_id'   and   @sortDirection = 'asc' then vendor_id end asc,
                case when @sortBy = 'vendor_name' and   @sortDirection = 'desc' then vendor_name end desc,
                case when @sortBy = 'vendor_name' and   @sortDirection = 'asc' then vendor_name end asc,
                vendor_id
        ) as RowNumber, * from #TempResults
    ) RowData
    where   RowNumber between @FirstRow and @LastRow
    order by RowNumber


    
end
```

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in the Web API method, when using Angular and Postman, whether the parameters are correct and the data table ("dt") contains value? Besides, try to add the output parameter via a SqlParameter object, like this:`SqlParameter outputPara = new SqlParameter(); outputPara.ParameterName = "@TotalRows"; outputPara.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output; outputPara.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;  cmd.Parameters.Add(outputPara);`. After executing the sql command (Fill method), get the return value using:`string RetrievedEmpId = outputPara.Value.ToString();`.

Comment: Firstly, The angular code, will not be with us. I'm not facing any issue with postman test, Where I'm able to get expected result. Anyhow I'll try with SqlParameter object as you suggest.